# How to set a formatted array results through PHP

Tags: php

I have an array that return like this, it shows on multiple lines and this is a system generated.

I want to convert the array into one liner results through PHP. Please see the sample below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => ping via eth0 2012-6-27 8:18:31   YES 
ping via eth0 2012-6-27 8:18:36  NO!!!
ping via eth1 2012-6-27 8:18:36   YES : ping via eth1 2012-7-19 7:48:3   YES 
ping via eth2 2012-7-19 7:48:3  not check
ping via eth3 2012-7-19 7:48:3   YES 
)
```

To return one line only or something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ping via eth0 2012-6-27 8:18:31 YES : ping via eth0 2012-6-27 8:18:36  NO!!! : ping via eth1 2012-6-27 8:18:36  YES : ping via eth1 2012-7-19 7:48:3 YES : ping via eth2 2012-7-19 7:48:3  not check : ping via eth3 2012-7-19 7:48:3 YES 
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: the above one is not multiple line, its in one line . May be you have use `var_dump` for viewing this .

Comment: Hi Yogesh, that result came from a var_dump. Found out when I tried to save data into CSV and it has multiple row. So I investigate through var_dump and that is what i saw.

Comment: okk...so now you are having some answers, try this..

Comment: @Yogesh, which one should i try? thanks.

Comment: i have posted answer check it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
$str = "ping via eth0 2012-6-27 8:18:31   YES 
ping via eth0 2012-6-27 8:18:36  NO!!!
ping via eth1 2012-6-27 8:18:36   YES 
ping via eth1 2012-7-19 7:48:3   YES 
ping via eth2 2012-7-19 7:48:3  not check
ping via eth3 2012-7-19 7:48:3   YES ";

$str = preg_replace ('/[\n\r]/', ' : ', $str);


print_r($str);
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/NPuAzf

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in $a[0], then this should do it:

```
$a[0] = preg_replace ('/[\n\r]/+', ' : ', $a[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you array has more than one line, you can use:

```
foreach ($entries as &$entry) {
  $entry = preg_replace('/[\r\n]', ':', $entry);
}
```

Comment: this does not show anything after. 

$entries = $row['data01'];
foreach ($entries as &$entry) {
  $entry = preg_replace('/[\r\n]', ':', $entry);
}